# How to Group By on the Vector Field

Tags: database, linq, group-by

I am working Linq Query, but I am not able to Group by with Vector field.

and my Linq Query is like this..

```
var Query = (from a in Helper.db.AccountStatement
                             join b in Helper.db.BankAccount on a.BankAccId equals b.BankAccId
                             join c in Helper.db.BankBranch on b.BankBranchId equals c.BankBranchId
                             join d in Helper.db.Bank on c.BankId equals d.BankId
                             where b.AccType == AccType && a.ActiveStatement == true && b.ActiveAccount == true && b.UserId == UserId
                             group new{ a,b,d} by new {b.BankAccId,d.Name,b.AccNumber,a.ClosingBalance,d.Logo} into h
                             select new clsFillBankSymmary
                             {

                                 BankAccountId = h.Key.BankAccId,
                                 BankName = h.Key.Name,
                                 BankAccountNo =h.Key.AccNumber,
                                 ClosingBalance = h.Key.ClosingBalance,
                                 BankLogo = (byte[])h.Key.VectorLogo.ToArray()
                             });


                    return Query;`
```

Thanks...!!!

Comment: This is the type of Binary type into the Database...@@

Comment: It will be nice if u post ur sample code here which is not working,so anybody will suggest any modification..

Comment: Ya sure I am putting my code.see the above Query..

Comment: this is not sql don't you just want the bankaccountid?

Comment: that is I know, what I am trying to do is I want to group by to the Image. if it is possible in Linq or not. if it is possible then how..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As of LINQ, changing the DB type of the Vector column to **varbinary(MAX)** should do the trick.